# Why does calling Controller.View with no arguments not clear the ViewData.Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I use the same controller instance in all of my tests, and just discovered (because my tests run in an arbitrary order) that if you call `Controller.View` with no arguments, it will pass back the same `ViewDataDictionary` that was created by a previous call to `Controller.View` which had arguments!

A trivial example (with NUnit and MvcContrib)

```vb
<Test()> _
Public Sub Test_A()
    Dim r As ViewResult = MockController.MethodWhichReturnsViewData().AssertViewRendered()

    Assert.IsNotNull(r.Model)
End Sub

<Test()> _
Public Sub Test_B()
    Dim r As ViewResult = MockController.MethodWhichDoesNotReturnViewData().AssertViewRendered()

    Assert.IsNull(r.Model) '<==== fails, has the same view data as Test_A!
End Sub
```

This is bad for my tests (obviously).  I can imagine two solutions, neither of which I like, any suggestions?  (As a bonus, can anyone understand why MS designed it this way?)

1. Explicitly specify `Nothing` as the model for all empty calls to `Controller.View`
2. Add a method to `TestSetUp` which clears the model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you are creating a new instance of your SUT (Subject Under Test) for each unit test. In NUnit that would be done inside a method decorated with the [`[Setup]`](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=setup&r=2.4) attribute:

```
<Setup()> _
Public Sub Init()
    ' Instantiate the SUT here
    MockController = ...
End Sub
```

Don't use any static fields. `MockController` should be a private instance field of your test fixture class.

Comment: I was doing some expensive mocking (.5 sec +) on the `MockController`, so I was trying to avoid reinitializing, then I ended up just getting rid of the mocking instead (most of my tests do not use it).  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe in a real web application (i.e. not a test mock) a separate controller instance is created for every request. So in your tests you should probably do the same.